# Using the tar command to display all files in a .tar archive to a file and to standard output

Tags: linux

Is it possible to direct that input from this command to a file and also to standard output? 
tar -t all.tar
Also Is there a way to kill all processes running lets say an xclock?

Comment: `man tee`. `man `pkill`. 1 Q per posting please, and these are not programming Qs. Use http://superuser.com for this level of Q. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

you can use pipe the output of `tar -t all.tar` to the command `tee`

```
tar -t all.tar | tee output_file_name
```